# sed command inside sed

Tags: sed

Is it possible to run `sed` command inside `sed`, something like this:

```
sed -i.bak -e '${sed -n 1,1p file.txt},$d' output.file
```

I want first line of `file.txt` which is number to be input parameter for `output.file` where all lines after that line will be deleted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not a `sed` command inside `sed`, that's just a replacement that your shell makes before actually caling `sed`. Just use proper quoting and parentheses, and you're done:

```
sed -i.bak -e "$(sed -n 1,1p file.txt),\$d" output.file
```

Double quotes allow process substitution inside (single quotes don't), and `$()` syntax means that the result of the inner command is captured and substituted. Note that `\$` had to be escaped to prevent `$d` being interpreted as a variable.

A less confusing way of writing the same thing would be

```
n=$(sed -n 1,1p file.txt)
sed -i.bak -e "${n}\$d" output.file
```

You can also write it like `"${n}"',$d'`, in `bash` you can concatenate differenlty quoted strings (including unquoted strings) simply by placing them one next to the other.

Also, you may want to write `sed -n '1{p;q}' file.txt`. First of all, you don't have to write a range if you only specify one line number. Secondly, if you quit after printing the first line (`q`), it doesn't read the entire file for no reason - more efficient. Because it's a first line, `-n` can also be omitted. Or, you could use `head -n1 file.txt`.

Comment: Obviously you can pipe it - not sure if it has to be necessarily 'inside' it!  eg sed -n 2,6p <input.txt> | sed 's/[a-z]/5/g'

Comment: Or just `sed q file.txt`.